# Проблемы при установке Linux Mint рядом с Win10

Tags: linux, linux-mint

Установил Linux Mint рядом с Windows 10. Проблема следующая: при нажатии Backspace печатает скобку, при нажатии " (э) - работает как Backspace. И еще несколько клавиш работают не так как надо. Как исправить проблему?

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего не правильно выбрана клавиатура. Поищите настройку клавиатуры в Linux Mint.
И попробуйте выбрать Generic 105 key